# How to re-order rows by ID in natural order

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I order the rows like this :

If I have these rows with numeric IDs :

> 1 | 2 | 3 | 100 | 4

The query will order them like so :

> 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

Updating the row with ID of **100** to **4** and the row with ID of  **4** to **5**

in other words

Updating the rows that are not in order.

Comment: They are numeric. I don't know what are you talking about.

Comment: Then what is the problem just ORDER BY will work... and I still don't understand why the data is different between the two.

Comment: You're going to have to expand on this; it's too difficult to infer from the question what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I edited the question. I thought my question was clear oh well I guess that's why I get so many down votes...

Comment: This question needs way more information. What data types are the columns? If they are numeric/int why not just use order by?

Comment: As It states in the question I want to 'Edit the row with ID of 100 to 4 and the row with ID of 4 to 5'. From what I know order by doesn't do that?

Comment: @l0oky if you want to update values look into the update statment  Update tableName SET ColumnName = Value WHERE columnNuame = 100

Comment: @KevinKunderman I know I need to update but what If I don't know the number of rows. What would the query look like?

Comment: So you want to insert the row number into the ID field? What's the point of the ID? Generally there's no intrinsic row numbering in a SQL database.

Comment: It seems like you're asking in what order the rows were inserted? If so, most database systems don't track that, you'd have to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: @hvd WHAT IS SO UNCLEAR ABOUT MY QUESTION GUYS?! I just want to order the rows updating the rows that are not in order!

Comment: Oh, you *want* a query that updates them to `1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5`... What was unclear about your question is that it looked like you had a query that already did that, and you *didn't* want that.

Comment: @hvd Blame stackoverflow for that. I can't add a new line that easily.

Comment: @l0oky You'd actually want to blame markdown, but don't blame that either.

Comment: @Bracketworks So are they going to reopen my question? I need answers..

Comment: 1. Your "rows" are columns, not rows. If you mean rows, please edit your question so they are rows. 2. Show us your SELECT statements. 3. Show us your UPDATE statement. 4. How on Earth could a "row" containing "100" be selected to show "5"? 5. UPDATES are not ordered so I have no idea what "Updating the rows that are not in order" is supposed to mean. Please explain.

Comment: I edited your question summary to use the word **re-order** instead of order.  Hopefully that makes it more clear.  If not, feel free to change it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mysql> create table t (i int);

mysql> insert into t values (1), (2), (3), (100), (4);

mysql> select * from t;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|  100 |
|    4 |
+------+

mysql> set @seq := 0;

mysql> update t set i = (@seq:=@seq+1);
Rows matched: 5  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
```

---

Re the comment from @ChristianKuetbach makes a good point.  I answered a way to accomplish what the question asks, but the question wasn't clear about whether these ID values are for a table's primary key.

**If** these values are primary key ID's, then you should reconsider renumbering them in the way you are describing.  The primary key values are required to be unique, but not consecutive.  You should never rely on auto-generated numbers being consecutive or even in order.  You can always get missing numbers because of DELETE, or ROLLBACK, or failed INSERT that still generates an ID.  Trying to force the ID's to be sorted is senseless at best, and will probably result in confusion of data references.

Comment: But why would I want to do this. If these are generic IDs, just don't care about them. MMaybe, they are used in URLs. So reordering may make  links point to different information.